# Limit MySQL's RAM memory use

Tags: mysql, linux

What can cause MySQL from using 43.6% of my memory on a Centos6 VPS server?  Note that I removed all `top` listings other than MySQL.  The VPS is only running a single Concrete5 website.  I've restarted MySQL and even rebooted the server but no change.

```
Tasks:  40 total,   1 running,  39 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1048576k total,   989376k used,    59200k free,        0k buffers
Swap:   524288k total,        0k used,   524288k free,   223392k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1929 mysql     20   0 1117m 446m 6240 S  0.0 43.6   0:00.42 mysqld

mysql> SELECT table_schema                                        "DB Name",
    ->    Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB"
    -> FROM   information_schema.tables
    -> GROUP  BY table_schema;
+--------------------+---------------+
| DB Name            | DB Size in MB |
+--------------------+---------------+
| concrete5          |          10.1 |
| information_schema |           0.0 |
| mysql              |           2.4 |
| performance_schema |           0.0 |
| school_db          |          23.5 |
+--------------------+---------------+
5 rows in set (1.07 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Hi, I would suggest to check the buffer configuration and caches of your server. Caches usually pre-allocate memory before you actually use it. Is it a development environment or a production environment?

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti  Mostly development.  It is a future dashboard for a school district.  Are the buffer configuration and caches specific to MySQL, or Linux?